# How do I solve $\ln(x^2 − 1) − \ln(x − 1) = 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I need to solve the following:

> $$\ln(x^2 − 1) − \ln(x − 1) = 2$$

But I am not entirely sure how to solve this.

I know that you can combine them into a fraction but then how would you simplify from there?

Comment: Try using $\ln(a)-\ln(b)=\ln(\frac{a}{b})$

Comment: **Hint:** Note that $\ln(x^2-1)=\ln((x-1)(x+1)=\ln(x-1)+\ln(x+1)$ and the $\ln(x-1)$ term cancels out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\ln(x)-\ln(y)=\ln(\frac{x}{y})$. Then use the fact that $e^{\ln(x)}=x$. This will eliminate all of the logs in your equation, and turn it into a manageable function of $x$.

Answer (score 3):

$\ln(x^2 - 1) = \ln((x + 1)(x - 1)) = \ln(x + 1) + \ln(x - 1), \tag 1$

assuming all the $\ln$ terms are well-defined; thus,

$\ln(x^2 - 1) - \ln(x - 1) = \ln(x + 1); \tag 2$

then

$\ln(x + 1) = 2, \tag 3$

or

$x + 1 = e^2, \tag 4$

yielding

$x = e^2 -1. \tag 5$

It is easy to see all the $\ln$ terms make sense here, since $e > 2.5 \Longrightarrow e^2 > 6.25 \Longrightarrow e^2 - 1 > 5.5$; also, $e > 2.5 \Longrightarrow e + 1 >3.5 \; \text{and} \; e - 1 > 1.5$ so all the logarithms are defined and positive.

A check:  with $x$ as in (5)

$x^2 = e^4 - 2e^2 + 1, \tag 6$

so

$x^2 - 1 = e^4 - 2e^2 =e^2(e^2 - 2) = (x + 1)(x - 1), \tag 6$

and $\ln$ takes over from here . . . we get

$\ln(x^2 - 1) = \ln(e^2(e^2 - 2)) = \ln e^2 + \ln(e^2 - 2) = 2 \ln e + \ln(x - 1), \tag 7$

etc . . .

Comment: (The last minor step is to check if all of the logarithms are defined for $x=e^2-1$)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt:  OK?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt:  I think you left out a "$" sign; hare to read!

Comment: Just a small thing to point out. If it had been$$\ln(1-x^2)-\ln(1-x)=2$$the result would be the same, though neither logarithm here is well-defined for $x=e^2-1$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt:  Engaging, I'll have to sleep on that one . . . .$zzzzzzzzzz$ . . . .

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Condense the logarithm: $\ln\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}\right)=2$ and that becomes $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=e^2$.(Why?)

Now as far as the left-hand side simplification is concerned, can you let your thoughts go over that? It should become a linear equation for you to solve. 
Give it a try

Answer (score -1):

$\ln(x^2−1)−\ln(x−1)=2$

$\ln(x^2−1)=2+\ln(x−1)$

$e^{\ln(x^2−1)}=e^{2+\ln(x−1)}$

$e^{\ln(x^2−1)}=e^2e^{\ln(x−1)}$

$x^2−1=(e^2)(x−1)$

$x^2+(-e^2)x+(e^2-1)=0$

Now it's a quadratic

OR

$x^2−1=(e^2)(x−1)$

$(x+1)(x-1)=(e^2)(x−1)$

$x+1=e^2$

$x=e^2-1$

Comment: Cute, but  $x^2 -1 = (e^2)(x - 1)$ directly yields $x + 1 = e^2$,  Endorsed.

Comment: @RobertLewis ah, the (x-1) can be factored out. Well, goes to show there are several ways to solve a problem (mine just happens to be a worse way) ;0

Comment: Not so bad, no so bad.  I thought the quadratic was an engaging touch, though strictly speaking unecessary.  Cheers!